# Objects won't Render

Tags: rendering, interface, renderman-render-engine

I a modeling this little house and then I render it only to see that the door I just modeled is the only thing that shows up.If I create something new that does render anyhow.
 [image]

I am using renderman and I thought maybe that's the problem but then I tried rendering in blender internal and cycles and the other parts of the house still wont show up.I then changed the display to only rendered objects and except the door everything was invisible, although they do appear in preview rendering both in cycles and blender internal, not in renderman preview rendering cause renderman uses the same files for rendering the actual thing. I also tried to save that file and append everything form the original file to a new instance but that didn't help either.

So,does anyone know how I can get my models to appear in the render ?

I know now this isn't a renderman problem but something in blender itself so i posted it here

any help provided would be appreciated and I apologize for my poor english

Comment: hard to say, you show little details, for one, your hidden objects could be disabled for rendering in the outliner...

Comment: um...well thanks, just saw that they were disabled in the outliner and now I feel stupid for not checking there.